# Fatal error in Buddypress, "Call to undefined function bp_get_settings_slug()"

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am developing a website using Buddypress and after creating the register page, when someone wants to sign up, after typing the info and press the sign up button, this error appears:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function bp_get_settings_slug() in /home/yeboah2/public_html/winderrands/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-core/bp-core-filters.php on line 1072

Instead of redirecting the new user to the activation page, it doesn't, that error shows up but on the users page. I see the new user created but the user can't activate his/her account.

this is where the error generated from...

```
// Who is the email going to?
    $recipient = $email->get( 'to' );
    if ( $recipient ) {
        $recipient = array_shift( $recipient );
        $user_obj  = $recipient->get_user( 'search-email' );

        $tokens['recipient.email'] = $recipient->get_address();
        $tokens['recipient.name']  = $recipient->get_name();

        if ( ! $user_obj && $tokens['recipient.email'] ) {
            $user_obj = get_user_by( 'email', $tokens['recipient.email'] );
        }

        if ( $user_obj ) {
            $tokens['recipient.username'] = $user_obj->user_login;
            if ( bp_is_active( 'settings' ) && empty( $tokens['unsubscribe'] ) ) {
                $tokens['unsubscribe'] = esc_url( sprintf(
                    '%s%s/notifications/',
                    bp_core_get_user_domain( $user_obj->ID ),
                    bp_get_settings_slug()
                ) );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Where did this `bp_get_settings_slug() ` function come from?

Comment: There's [several possible solutions here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Call+to+undefined+function+bp_get_settings_slug). Readers will probably need to know what version of Buddypress you're running, and what plugins you have enabled.

Comment: **Please add your code to the question**, [by editing it](//stackoverflow.com/posts/45111335/edit), rather than using the comments. A formatting tool `{}` is available.

Comment: it's been added....

Comment: See my remarks earlier about versions/plugins too.

Comment: thank you so much, i am checking it out

Comment: Make sure that you have Account Settings component activated in BuddyPress Settings.